# How do I center <img> as background with CSS or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just launched a website for a client that use `background-size: cover;` to get a full size background picture, and it doesn't work in mobile Safari.

So I have used an `img` tag to show a picture, used JS to find the aspect ratio of the viewport, and set full width/height accordingly depending on the aspect ratio.

Now, I wonder how to center this picture in the viewport. Either in JS or in CSS.

The code:

```css
div.si {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="si" style="background: url('bg.jpg') no-repeat fixed center; background-size: cover; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; z-index: -1;">

  <img src="bg.jpg" style="width: auto; height: auto; min-height: 100%; min-width: 100%;" />

</div>
```

Never mind inline CSS for now ;)

Basically the `img` will overflow outside the viewport, so I wonder how I can anchor it in the center, and not in the top left (`top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0;`). I find this difficult because the image is bigger than the viewport, which is why it seems to be harder than `margin: auto;` or `text-align: center;`.

Do i perhaps need JS to make it work?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Perhaps `max-width: 100vw; max-height: 100vh;`?

Comment: `max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%`

Comment: @BenjaminUlstein can you provide code here .?

Comment: you can still use `background-size: cover` for the `div`... as far as I know the only problem with it in mobile safari is that it stretches the image over the whole body size if applied to `body`. so if you place a 100% width & height `div` with `position: fixed` and background-image in the background, it should work.

Comment: @SimonHänisch `background-size: cover` is on `div.si`, which is a 100% width/height `div`, parent of the image. I applied `position: fixed`, but the background still seems to stretch over the whole body vertically. 

@haim770 If I understand correctly, this is about sizing, and I have already made the IMG cover the entire viewport in all screen sizes. The main problem is that the I want the content of the photo to be centered, not anchored to top left when shown in portrait on mobile.
@Mr_Green Same as above, I believe.

Comment: @BenjaminUlstein have you tried the following background properties on your div: `background-image: url('bg.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: center center;` ? `position: fixed`stretching over the whole body with `height: 100%` is expected now that I think it over... you can try viewport height units or use javascript to set height to viewport height. Or you can make the whole `html` and `body` fixed and 100% height and use `overflow: scroll` for your content

Comment: Also I found this: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/full-page-backgrounds-on-ios-background-size-cover/ with a solution in this post: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/full-page-backgrounds-on-ios-background-size-cover/page/3/#post-203556 (using modernizr) and in this post: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/full-page-backgrounds-on-ios-background-size-cover/page/4/#post-210422 (using viewport units) and a codepen using media queries: http://codepen.io/j_holtslander/pen/RPOJVj

Answer (score 0):

Hi may be you can use **"object-fit: cover;"** property in css that may help you

you guys must check the browser-suport before use.

> [**Browser support**](http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit)

here is the [Link reference](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/)

and it's better to use the media Queries than using the **jquery** methods as it can be handled b the **css**

Comment: but of course, IE doesn't support it. http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Comment: @SamiaRuponti hii he can make a hack it by adding class to the element only if the "mobile Safari."(as mentioned in question) is detected by the jquery module and apply "object-fit" with that class added right ??

Comment: sure he can, if he was only using the `img` hack for mobile image. `object-fit` support isn't that great among older android phones (4.4.4 supports it, UC browser still doesn't). I suppose he has to first decide how backward he wants to go in terms of support. even then, this is a extremely hacky trick.

Comment: @SamiaRuponti yup i am not lagging behind to accept that it's hacky, so i have added the note and browser support link added with my answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correctly, you're trying to make the background image responsive in different view ports by creating another img inside your div.si?

Try using this to your div.si.

```css
div.si {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

To make it responsive though, you either need to update the background-size property on smaller viewport. You either need to sacrifice a portion of that background or have it squash in smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this in your image css :

```
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Don't forget the prefixes on the transform line.